# Saving the content being emailed as an attachment in google drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have written a script that attaches the content of the sheet as an attachment and emails it.

This is for invoicing. Once an invoice is generated, the invoice is sent as a PDF to the vendor. Now, i want these sent invoices documented in google drive every time they are sent

Now, i want this attachment PDF to be saved to a google drive folder every time the email is triggered

This is an invoicing sheet.

```
function emailSpreadsheetAsPDF() {
  const sheetToPrint = "Invoice"; // name of the sheet to print
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // the sheets to use

  const subject = `Invoice`; // the subject of the email

  const shID = ss.getSheetByName(sheetToPrint).getSheetId(); // the ID of the sheet
  const url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SS_ID/export?'.replace('SS_ID', ss.getId()); // url of the spreadsheet
  const exportOptions =
    'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' + // export as pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
    '&size=A4'+ // size of the PDF (legal / A4 / letter)
    '&portrait=true'+ // orientation of the PDF (false for landscape)
    '&fitw=true'+ // fit to page width (false for actual size)
    '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false'+ // hide optional headers and footers
    '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false'+ // hide page numbers and gridlines
    '&fzr=false'+ // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
    '&gid='+shID; // the sheet's Id
  var params = {method:"GET",headers:{"authorization":"Bearer "+ ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};
  
  // generate the PDF file
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+exportOptions, params).getBlob();
  
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var resp = ui.alert('Are you sure?',ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  if(resp == ui.Button.YES)
  {
  var ssheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Invoice");
  var tsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Invoice Archives");

  var tindex = tsheet.getLastRow();
  var count = tsheet.getRange(tindex,1).getValue();
  tindex = Number(tindex) + 1; 
  var count = tsheet.getRange(tindex,1).setValue(Number(count)+1);
  ssheet.getRange(22,8).copyTo(tsheet.getRange(tindex,7), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false); //Invoice Amout  
  
  ssheet.getRange(7,8).copyTo(tsheet.getRange(tindex,15), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  ssheet.getRange(21,8).copyTo(tsheet.getRange(tindex,16), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  ssheet.getRange(10,8).copyTo(tsheet.getRange(tindex,17), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false); // admin name
  ssheet.getRange(11,8).copyTo(tsheet.getRange(tindex,18), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false); // admin email
  ssheet.getRange(12,8).copyTo(tsheet.getRange(tindex,19), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false); // sales lead email
  var invid = tsheet.getRange(tindex,2).getValue();
  var invamount = tsheet.getRange(tindex,7).getValue();
  var adminname = tsheet.getRange(tindex,17).getValue();
  var aemail = tsheet.getRange(tindex,18).getValue();
  var semail = tsheet.getRange(tindex,19).getValue();
  var email = aemail + ',' + semail ;
  Logger.log(email);
  var body = '<p>Hello '+adminname+',</p> <p>Greetings from Begig! Hope you are doing well.</p> <p>Please find an invoice attached to this email of value ₹'+invamount+'. Request you to process the payment against it at the earliest</p> <p>&nbsp;</p> <p>--</p> <p>Regards</p> <p>Ops Team - Begig</p>'
  // send the email to the specified address with the specified body text and attached PDF file
    GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {
      htmlBody: body,
      attachments: [{
            fileName: "Invoice - "+ invid+".pdf",
            content: response.getBytes(),
            mimeType: "application/pdf"
        }]

    });
    raiseinvoice();
  }
}
```

Comment: What's keeping you from doing that?

Comment: I just dont know how to do that. I tried using DriveApp.createFile(Name, response.getBytes(), mimetype:PDF) and a PDF with non sensical numbers are getting saved

Answer (score 1):

To save the pdf, you will have to add

```
const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('_______if of folder______');
folder.createFile(response.setName('______name_of_file_____'));
```